# PyQt5 call filebrowser

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm trying to integrate a file browser into my code.

For this I am using from github: https://github.com/vfxpipeline/filebrowser/blob/master/fileBrowser.py

How do I call it in a Dialog window?

I tried the following:

```
class UIFunctionDialog(QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.ui = MyFileBrowser()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
```

while the code from github is in a separate file which I imported at the beginning of my main. In QtDesigner I added treeview.

When running the Programm the filebrowser won't popup.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: What's wrong with [QFileDialog](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html)?